# Passing div id to directive in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following directive:

```
.directive('addfields',function($compile){

  return function(scope,element){
    element.on("click",function(){
    var enviroElement = angular.element('<enviro-variables></enviro-variables>');
      var el = $compile(enviroElement)(scope);
      console.log(el);
      angular.element(document.getElementById('moreEnviromentVariables')).append($compile(el)(scope))
    })
  }
})
```

This works to an extent. When this directive is called it creates me a new enviroVariables element which is another directive I wrote. It looks like this:

```
<div id = "formSection">
                  <div class="row rowmargin">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="key" id="key" ng-model="key" ng-change="updateJson()" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="value" ng-model="value" ng-change="updateJson()"  ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" >
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
```

The problem is that because I am creating an element with the same div id, when I do dependency injection it updates all environment Variables rather than just one.

Is there a way I can pass or generate a new div id for each instance of  variable I create?  I'm guessing I should be able to pass it in scope:{} below but cant get it work

```
 .directive('enviroVariables',function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
scope:{},


    templateUrl:'scripts/directives/enviromentVariablesDiv.html'
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is this id `moreEnviromentVariables` defined? And where are you using `addfields`?

Comment: Updated it for some clarity,thanks

Comment: Sorry my answer was Angular 2-centric, removed it. Maybe you could work with a CSS class instead of an ID (it's still relevant that you should not have duplicate DOM element IDs in your app).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the `addfields` directive return function

```
  return function(scope,element){
    element.on("click",function(){
    var enviroElement = angular.element('<enviro-variables></enviro-variables>');
      var el = $compile(enviroElement)(enviroElement.scope());
      console.log(el);
      angular.element(document.getElementById('moreEnviromentVariables')).append(el)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you talk me through this please?

Comment: no, it doesn't make the divs independant and give them an id which is my goal.

Comment: Can you make a plunker?